# How CES function with integral becomes min function in the limit

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, economics

I wonder how a CES function over a continuum of goods,

$$\left(\int_1^\infty c(\theta)^\delta g(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}$$

where $c(\theta), g(\theta)>0 \forall \theta\in\left[1,\infty\right)$, collapses to a minimum function in the limit as $\delta \to -\infty$.

I have seen [the answer to a very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024020/limit-of-ces-function-as-p-goes-to-infty#answer-1043670) and below is my adaption of it to this problem:

First, let $\theta' \in \arg\min_{\theta\in\left[1,\infty\right)}c(\theta)$. Then,

\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta \to -\infty} \left(\int_1^\infty c(\theta)^\delta g(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta} &= \lim_{\delta \to -\infty} \left(c(\theta')^\delta g(\theta')\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{c(\theta)}{c(\theta')}\right)^\delta \frac{g(\theta)}{g(\theta')} \mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta} \\
&= \lim_{\delta \to -\infty} c(\theta') g(\theta')^\frac{1}{\delta}\left(\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{c(\theta)}{c(\theta')}\right)^\delta \frac{g(\theta)}{g(\theta')} \mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\dfrac{1}{\delta} \\
&= c(\theta') \lim_{\delta \to -\infty} g(\theta')^\frac{1}{\delta}\left(\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{c(\theta)}{c(\theta')}\right)^\delta \frac{g(\theta)}{g(\theta')} \mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\dfrac{1}{\delta} \\
&= c(\theta')
\end{align}

It is the very last step that I can't really get my head around. I'm fine with that, as $\delta\to-\infty$, $g(\theta')^\frac{1}{\delta}\to 1$ and also that if $c(\theta)<c(\theta')$ then $\left(\frac{c(\theta)}{c(\theta')}\right)^\delta\to 0$ and if $c(\theta)=c(\theta')$ then $\left(\frac{c(\theta)}{c(\theta')}\right)^\delta\to 1$.

1. How can I know that the entire integral goes to unity? This could perhaps be rephrased: how do I show that

$$\lim_{\delta\to-\infty} \left(\int_1^\infty \theta^\delta\mathrm{d}\theta\right)^\frac{1}{\delta}=1?$$

2. Also, and more fundamentally, under what circumstances can a limit be factorized so that it is the product of the "factor limits"?

Comment: Can you provide background for math people who don't know CES fcns?: 0) are c, g > 0? 1) Why does the integral exist? are there conditions on c and g that make this happen? 2) Why does the arg min exist?

Comment: If you define $f(\theta)=c(\theta)^{-1}$ and define $p=-\delta$ then this is very similar to the proof that the $L^p$-norm approaches the $\infty$-norm as $p\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have tried to include further details. Let's just assume that the arg min exists. The existence of the arg min is not really at the heart of the question, which is more about the limit of the integral.

Comment: Could you supply a link to the proof you are referring to, @cantorhead ?

Comment: is it not just about showing that the integral is bounded?

Comment: Question is $c$ a differentiable function?

Comment: Heres a [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242779/limit-of-lp-norm). You'll need to do something like $\int \cdot g(\theta)\  d \theta = \int \cdot \ dw$ first. Their proof follows different lines, though, I think because it requires fewer assumptions.

Comment: At top you say you want $\delta \to -\infty$ but in the equations you have $\lim_{\delta\to\infty}$ is this intended?

Comment: I don't seem to have the rep to add the functional analysis tag, but I think it would be appropriate.

Comment: @tired: $c$ is a differentiable function of $\theta$ but not of $\delta$, so I think that in this problem $c(\theta)$ for each $\theta$ can be viewed as a constant.

Comment: @cantorhead: All the limits should be $\delta\to-\infty$. Thanks for spotting the typo!

Comment: @tired: it could be that I would need to show that the integral is bounded, but I am afraid that I don't know. That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @cantorhead: Thanks for the link! I will have a look at it.